# Save Remote Image to local server Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to Save Remote Image to local server using Phils Curl srcipt in Codeigniter.

To ensure directory is there with proper permissions I have:

```
if (!is_dir('images')){
  mkdir('./images', 0777, true);
}
```

Here is what I tried.. ( [Source](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/171346/#815950) )

```
 $this->load->library('curl');
 $this->load->helper('file');

 $remoteURL = 'http://fermeteogranada.com/camara.jpg';
 $img = $this->curl->simple_get($remoteURL);
 $localURL = './images/main.jpg';

 if ( ! write_file($localURL, $img)){
     $this->session->set_flashdata('err_message', 'Unable to write the file');
  }
```

It is creating a file named as main.jpg but with 0 bytes.

I also tried to use copy and file_get_content

```
if ( ! copy($localURL, $img)){
  $error = get_last_error();   
  $this->session->set_flashdata('err_message', $error['message']);
}


if ( ! file_put_content($localURL, file_get_content($img) )){
  $error = get_last_error();   
  $this->session->set_flashdata('err_message', $error['message']);
}
```

But It is also not working as well, It is not giving any error message.

Answer (score 0):

I would first debug $img data verify it has a bunch of binary junk in it.  You may also want to check the http status.  Perhaps the website is denying remote curls by user agent.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing this ?

```
  $remoteFile = 'http://fermeteogranada.com/camara.jpg';
  $remoteResource = file_get_contents($remoteFile);

  $saveTo = './images/main.jpg';
  file_put_contents($saveTo, $remoteResource);
```

I tried in local and it works just fine.

Comment: I am trying in local on Windows... I tried , It is Not working for me!!

Comment: Is your ‘allow_url_fopen‘ set on ‘true‘ in your php.ini ? If not, there is your problem ;-) http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Comment: Yes It is set properly. I have `'allow_url_fopen'=on` in my php.ini.

Comment: OK. I was trying to get some error message and this is what I got .. `Message: file_get_contents(http://fermeteogranada.com/camara.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`